# Hiding React Src From User Until Logged In

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router-v4

So I noticed when I ran my react app's production build's login screen from create-react-app that all of the source code for the app was available within the static/js folder. Basically, the code doesn't look any different from the code in my ide, on the production build.

I am wondering if there is a way to hide this behind a login screen? So that a user can't directly access these files unless the login is successful. I have looked around and was unable to find anything of use.

Comment: You can make the main content render only on the condition that the user's logged-in state is true, else it renders the login screen.

Comment: @stever but that doesn't hide the *source*

Comment: Not easily. You'd have to do some kind of code-splitting, then serve the relevant parts of the bundle securely. What's led to the requirement?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The client doesn't want the src for the main app to be visible before auth. ? security concerns?

Comment: I'd suggest you try and dig into what underlies that requirement, then.

Comment: I can tell you that it is security concerns, for non auth clients being able to rebuild parts of the ui without being authed.

Comment: And why does that matter? The client should still not be able to see *data* they aren't allowed to, as they can't get it from the APIs; why is it a problem that they can *"rebuild parts of the ui"*? This is what I mean by digging.

Comment: The fact that a non auth user can get a sense of what is behind the login.

Comment: Interesting. I guess you’ll need to redirect your url to a separate authentication url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The js files from the production build should be minimized which would look a **lot** different than in your IDE. I assume what looks "the same" is looking at the source using developer tools. The solution for that is to not deploy the source map files (*.js.map). Those are the files that allow developer tools to transform the minimized code back to its original look.

Removing source maps makes it difficult for someone to learn from the code **easily**, but if there is sufficient motivation to do so, it can still certainly be reverse-engineered. There are also some parts that wouldn't be obfuscated much at all such as the URLs for API calls which would then give someone a lot more information to use as the basis for hacking attempts.

If you need to prevent seeing any version of the source for people that are not logged in, I would recommend building your app as two apps -- one that just contains the login portion and one with the rest. Code-splitting within one app won't do the trick (at least not without using a solution that is quite a bit more complicated to manage than the two-app option), because it just makes the download process lazy and it is still pretty easy for someone to determine what the other files are and download them. However, even splitting this into two apps only helps if you host the second app differently. This will require server-side protection that only serves the JavaScript files for the second app for a user that is logged in. This means either using a different sub-domain for the second app or at least a different directory on the server that has those protections baked in. How you would implement that protection depends on the details of your authentication approach and the technology stack being used on the server. Most likely, it means using a cookie set by the login process and then having the JS files for the second app served up by something that verifies the cookie before allowing the JS files to be served to the browser.

Comment: Why doesn't lazy loading work to achieve that? Here's an example of what I mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77232322/react-hide-code-from-sources-by-lazy-loading?noredirect=1#comment136155587_77232322

Comment: @DamjanVučina Because the initially downloaded portion of the app contains the information on how to download the lazily-loaded parts so it is very easy for someone to determine the names of the lazily-loaded files and download them even if your app doesn't get to the point of triggering the download.

Answer (score -1):

To overcome displaying your source code in production's build, try to build your app with

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false npm run build
```

Comment: This will still make it display, just minified.. What I want to do is ONLY display the components (within the minified file) that relate to the login screen and after login is successful I want to display everything else.