# React hide code from sources by lazy loading

Tags: reactjs, react-lazy-load

Is it possible to have a portion of my code not visible in the sources tab of the developer tools at all, until the user logs in. I know about not deploying source maps, but in theory that can still be reverse engineered. Or do I need to implement this as two apps, one as a "login app", and the other one as "private-app". The app is client side rendered (with react).

Could this work?

```
const LazyPrivateRoutes = lazy(() => import('./PrivateRoutes'));

// function component

const isLoggedIn = useSelector(AuthSelectors.isLoggedIn);

return (
 <Suspense fallback={<></>}>
   <BrowserRouter>
     <Switch>
      {isLoggedIn && <LazyPrivateRoutes />}
      <PublicRoute
        path={routes.login}
        component={<LoginPage />}
        isAuthenticated={isLoggedIn}
        />
     </Switch>
   </BrowserRouter>
 </Suspense>
)
```

Comment: Build it so it doesn't matter if they see the app source code - anything _secret_ should be behind an authenticated API.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not sure you understand the question. The app is behind an auth. My question is can the frontend code (that is behind the auth) be downloaded separately only after the user logs in?

Comment: If the frontend code _is_ "behind the auth", then inevitably the user will have to be logged in to download it. But this only works where you have other ways to authenticate the user _before_ getting to the SPA, e.g. with SSO. If that's **not** the case, you want them to log in _using the SPA_, then you'd generally make _the whole SPA_ public, and have anything that an unauthenticated user shouldn't be able to see driven by data from API endpoints that require authentication. Hiding source maps is "security through obscurity", i.e. not security.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't answer the above question. In order not to speak in generalities, can you take a look at my code example above? Is it possible to prevent having LazyPrivateRoutes component (and all the other components and files it imports) in the bundle until the user logs in? I tried the above and it doesn't achieve that, not sure why.

Comment: In order not to speak in generalities we'd need to know e.g.: how you were bundling the app; how you're doing code splitting to separate out the parts you want to be separately authenticated; how you're serving the app to differentially manage access to those files. But none of that changes what I've said, which is that you don't need to if you take the _much simpler_ path of moving anything actually secret out of the SPA entirely and loading it via the API.

Comment: I'm using create react app with webpack. Entire app is client side rendered. I'm doing code splitting as in the code example I attached in OP. I do not want anything to be separately authenticated, rather downloaded as a separate bundle, only after a user logs in. I know I can make my app be server side rendered, that is not the question. The requirement is for it to be client side rendered, and have part of the codebase be downloaded after login. I'm still unsure whether you think this is possible or not.